# Want to adjust the 1 page 2 column CV setting?

Tags: cv

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{doublespace}
%\setstretch{1.2}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CV}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=blue}

\setlength{\textwidth}{5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{660pt}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{42pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-20pt}

\newcommand{\ingreen}[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}


\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
%\huge{\textsc{Curriculum Vitae}}
%\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}

\huge{\textsc{Name}}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}



\section{Contact Information}
\begin{flushleft}

Email: \ingreen{abc@gmail.com} \\
Skype: abc\\
Mobile: +00-000-1234567 \\
Phone: +00-00-1234567
\end{flushleft}

\section{Objective}
\begin{flushleft}
 To become a good researcher in my field.
\end{flushleft}


\section{Education}

\begin{CV}
\item[\ingreen{August 2007--August 2009}]
\item[Master(Biochemistry)]
\item[University Name]
\item[City, Country]
\item[Area: Biochemistry]
\item[\ingreen{August 2002--September 2006}]
\item[BS(Hons)]
\item[University Name]
\item[City, Country]
\item[Area: Biology]
\end{CV}
\section{Research Work}
\begin{flushleft} My Master degree thesis is on \emph{Research}.
\end{flushleft}

\section{Technical Expertise}
\noindent
\begin{itemize}
\item  MATLAB, Mathematica, C/C++, \LaTeX, \LaTeX Draw, Mayura Draw, MS Office
\end{itemize}

\section{Area of Interest}
\noindent

\section{Hobbies $\&$ Sports}
\noindent
\begin{itemize}
\item Studying Books, Cricket, Watching Sports Channels
\item Music, Movies, Photography
\end{itemize}


\section{References}





\end{document}
```

1. First Problem to centralizing the Name.
2. Second Equalize the horizontal lines.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use the optional argument to `\twocolumn`; you can also set `\columnsep` and `\columnseprule` to the desired values.

In the example I have removed the unused `tabularx` package (add it if needed) and also the obsolete package `ae`. If you don't have the CM-Super font package and the printout appears fuzzy, add `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CV}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=blue}

\setlength{\textwidth}{5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{660pt}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{42pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-20pt}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\newcommand{\ingreen}[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[%
  \begin{center}
  \huge\textsc{Curriculum Vitae}

  \textsc{Name}
  \end{center}
]



\section{Contact Information}
\begin{flushleft}

Email: \ingreen{abc@gmail.com} \\
Skype: abc\\
Mobile: +00-000-1234567 \\
Phone: +00-00-1234567
\end{flushleft}

\section{Objective}
\begin{flushleft}
 To become a good researcher in my field.
\end{flushleft}


\section{Education}

\begin{CV}
\item[\ingreen{August 2007--August 2009}]
\item[Master(Biochemistry)]
\item[University Name]
\item[City, Country]
\item[Area: Biochemistry]
\item[\ingreen{August 2002--September 2006}]
\item[BS(Hons)]
\item[University Name]
\item[City, Country]
\item[Area: Biology]
\end{CV}
\section{Research Work}
\begin{flushleft} My Master degree thesis is on \emph{Research}.
\end{flushleft}

\section{Technical Expertise}
\noindent
\begin{itemize}
\item  MATLAB, Mathematica, C/C++, \LaTeX, \LaTeX Draw, Mayura Draw, MS Office
\end{itemize}

\section{Area of Interest}
\noindent

\section{Hobbies $\&$ Sports}
\noindent
\begin{itemize}
\item Studying Books, Cricket, Watching Sports Channels
\item Music, Movies, Photography
\end{itemize}


\section{References}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is one possible solution where `multicol` package is used, rather than `\twocolumn`.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,multicol}
%\usepackage{doublespace}
%\setstretch{1.2}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CV}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=blue}

\setlength{\textwidth}{5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{660pt}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{42pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-20pt}

\newcommand{\ingreen}[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
%\huge{\textsc{Curriculum Vitae}}
%\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
\huge{\textsc{Name}}
\end{center}
%\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Contact Information}
\begin{flushleft}

Email: \ingreen{abc@gmail.com} \\
Skype: abc\\
Mobile: +00-000-1234567 \\
Phone: +00-00-1234567
\end{flushleft}

\section{Objective}
\begin{flushleft}
 To become a good researcher in my field.
\end{flushleft}

\section{Education}

\begin{CV}
\item[\ingreen{August 2007--August 2009}]
\item[Master(Biochemistry)]
\item[University Name]
\item[City, Country]
\item[Area: Biochemistry]
\item[\ingreen{August 2002--September 2006}]
\item[BS(Hons)]
\item[University Name]
\item[City, Country]
\item[Area: Biology]
\end{CV}
\section{Research Work}
\begin{flushleft} My Master degree thesis is on \emph{Research}.
\end{flushleft}

\section{Technical Expertise}
\noindent
\begin{itemize}
\item  MATLAB, Mathematica, C/C++, \LaTeX, \LaTeX Draw, Mayura Draw, MS Office
\end{itemize}

\section{Area of Interest}
\noindent
\vfill
\columnbreak
\section{Hobbies $\&$ Sports}
\noindent
\begin{itemize}
\item Studying Books, Cricket, Watching Sports Channels
\item Music, Movies, Photography
\end{itemize}


\section{References}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I  want a vertical line between two columns then which command is used in code.

Comment: Use `\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}` in preamble.

Comment: it is possible to add the Picture on the right top in this CV

Comment: @LaTeXKan I assume that is a question, not a statement. Yes, certainly. Use graphicx package and use these codes right after the `pagestyle` command `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\hfill
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-A}
\end{minipage}`